# Convert ifstream to istream

Tags: c++, casting

How would one go about casting a ifstream into a istream. I figure since ifstream is a child of istream I should be able to do so but I have been having problems with such a task.

```
std::istream & inputStr = std::cin;
  std::ostream & outputStr = std::cout;
  if(argc == 3){
    std::fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in);
    if(!inputFile){
        std::cerr << "Error opening input file";
        exit(1);
    }
    inputStr = inputFile;
.....
}
```

Comment: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.cpp/2004-09/0856.html

Comment: Indeed you can directly assign them, but if you're having problems, you should post your code so we know what's wrong.

Comment: You should not actually need to. You can just use the file stream in any place an istream is needed and the compiler will do an auto cast for you.

Comment: Added a code snippet which works just fine for setting the input stream to std::cin however I can't reset it to the file

Comment: I guess really my question is not how to cast them its how to re assign the stream.

Answer (score 31):

No cast is necessary.

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream    f;
    istream&    s   = f;
}
```

Comment: It would help IMHO to mention that this works because of Polymorphism, i.e. the fact that ifstream is a subclass of istream. (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: @Lee-Man: the OP already mentioned that (modulo terminology), so I didn't. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
std::ifstream* myStream;
std::istream* myOtherStream = static_cast<std::istream*>(myStream);
myOtherStream = myStream;   // implicit cast since types are related.
```

The same works if you have a reference (&) to the stream type as well.  `static_cast` is preferred in this case as the cast is done at compile-time, allowing the compiler to report an error if the cast is not possible (i.e. `istream` were not a base type of `ifstream`).

Additionally, and you probably already know this, you can pass a pointer/reference to an `ifstream` to any function accepting a pointer/reference to a `istream`.  For example, the following is allowed by the language:

```
void processStream(const std::istream& stream);

std::ifstream* myStream;
processStream(*myStream);
```

Comment: I think the `static_cast` in your first code block does not happen in-place so it needs to be assigned to an `std::istream` pointer: `std::istream* myStream2 = static_cast<std::istream*>(myStream);`.

Comment: Why o why o why would you pass a pointer when a reference would do?

Comment: @Martin: I was just showing flexibility of the language.  As it wasn't clear from the OP's question exactly what problem he/she is experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istream *istreamObj = dynamic_cast<std::istream *>(&ifStreamObj)
```

Comment: You forgot an asterisk in your dynamic cast. I think you meant `std::istream *istreamObj = dynamic_cast<std::istream *>(&ifStreamObj)`

Comment: Not only did you not verify the code was correct. There is no actual need for the cast. Take it out and it still compiles fine. When the compiler does work for you there is no need to actually do it yourself.

Comment: My sincere apologies.  My wrists have been slit, so no mortal may lay eyes again on my mistakes.  Relax a little, eh?  Adding a '*'...