# Switch streams based on some condition in cpp

Tags: c++, iostream, file-handling

I have a code in which I have two options of reading input from a file or from standard input. I want to switch the stream from `cin` to `fin` in case  of the `file_name` provided is a valid one. How could I implement it? A basic rough idea code is given here:

```
int main(){
    string default_file_name = "my_file.txt";
    string file_name = get_from_commandline_args();
    istream reader; // can't create this as constructor is private
    if(file_name == default_file_name) {
        ifstream fin; 
        fin.open (file_name);
        reader = fin;
    } else {
        reader = cin;
    }
    while(true) {
    // read input
    string str;
    reader >> str;
    }
}
```

this code is just rough Idea of what I want. Code is wrong as we can't create instance of `istream`

Comment: Besides being naive, what is wrong with your implementation? The more "correct" way to do this, is to have two classes of reader that implement the same interface, one using standard input and the other using a file.

Comment: @o_weisman we cannot create instance of istream that line `istream reader;` won't work

Comment: See how they do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080179/convert-ifstream-to-istream

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a valid use case for a raw pointer in C++:

```
int main(){
    string default_file_name = "my_file.txt";
    string file_name = get_from_commandline_args();
    istream* reader = nullptr;
    ifstream fin; 
    if(file_name == default_file_name) {
        fin.open (file_name);
        reader = &fin;
    } else {
        reader = &cin;
    }
    while(true) {
    // read input
    string str;
    (*reader) >> str;
    }
}
```

Just make the type with the common interface a pointer type:

```
istream* reader = nullptr;
```

Change the rest of the code accordingly.

Here's a compilable example: [Ex](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/702eee9f4330bb7a)